# Notify Instagram Post

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py, instagram-api

I'm trying to create a discord bot where the bot sends a message when an instagram account has posted something, but I can't find in the instagram's API or in any other API how can I code it... Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think instagram has a public API.

Answer (score 1):

You could code this with an browser-automation tool like [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/). You can then automate the process of logging in, going to a specific profile and notifying you if there has been a new post since the last time you checked.

Answer (score 0):

Instagram shutdown its Feed API a litte over a year ago that provided this functionality that IFTTT and others used.

[Instagram Platform Update](http://developers.instagram.com/post/133424514006/instagram-platform-update)

Not sure there's a way except continuous pulling of user's IG page and waiting for an update.